# sequence diagram in a specific situation

Tags: uml

Hello I'm studying sequence diagram.
For example there are 2 actors, 
an actor is a trader who has an online shop.
Another actor is a customer who buys the trader's products.
How do I represent the situation when the trader is storing the products into a database or when the customer is buying a product?
The possible use cases are insertProduct and buyProduct.
The database is part of the system, so no other actor communicates with the system.
I've not understood how to represent this situation when the communication among actors is not in "real-time".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to split things as @JimL suggests. Your use case is best be shown with an activity diagram where you have single actions representing the steps like search/pay/etc.

When you design your domain you will then find technical classes like `Store` etc. where your actor can send messages like `buy(item)` etc.

The whole story is somewhat more lengthy and will definitely be off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up two levels of interaction. One happens at the business level, in the "meat world", where people interact. The trader and customer might only interact directly when the customer has a question. The other happens at the system level, between an actor and the system. The latter would show how the trader stores a product OR how a customer buys a product, not both.